# Accessing AWS SQL Server remotely

Tags: sql-server, portforwarding, amazon-lightsail

I have deployed SQL Server on AWS LightSail. I have set the port `1433` in the console and on the AWS Windows environment to allow it to connect remotely. Now I want to forward the port in my mikrotik firewall i.e. `NAT`. I have done the below steps

```
IP > Firewall > NAT  +

Chain dstnat
Protocol 6 (tcp)
Dst. Port: 1433

Action tab
Action dst-nat
//stuck at below point
To Addresses:  (IP address of the pc on local lan you would like to port forward to) ex: 
192.168.88.2
To Ports:  1433

Click Ok
```

I am stuck at `To Address`. As I don't know what IP to add to it? As I have also tried to add the `IP address of my connected LAN`, `Local IP of AWS`, `Live IP of AWS`. But still, I am unable to access it.

**Reference of the solution:** [Port Forward 1433](https://forum.mikrotik.com/viewtopic.php?t=109232)

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Avoid doing this. Lightsail provides SSH support, so rather than opening up tcp/1433 to the whole internet you should instead use an SSH Tunnel to forward localhost:1433 (or some other port) on your machine over the SSH connection to port 1433 within your Lightsail instance.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning how can I do this ?